# List online Gtalk contacts

Tags: android, google-hangouts

I am looking for an Android application that can list amongst my Google Talk contact who is currently online, just like what I can see on the Gmail web interface:

[image]

[Hangouts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.talk&hl=en) doesn't seem to display who is online.